# How to async/await multiple uploads before final form submit?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I am trying to allow users to upload multiple files. Each file selected will trigger an `axios.post()` request... so if a user selects three files then there will be three separate `axios.post()` requests made to the server to upload the files.

There are also other fields in the form such as `Name` and `Description` which will be submitted when the user clicks the form submit button. However, I want the form submission to wait until ALL the files are uploaded first.

Here is a shortened version of the code for brevity:

```
<form @submit.prevent="sendForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input multiple ref="PostFiles" name="PostFiles" type="file" @change="selectFile">
  ... // other fields here
  <button type="submit" name="Send" value="Send"></button>
</form>


methods: {


     selectFile() {
               const this.Form.UploadFiles = this.$refs.PostFiles.files; // all files selected by user to upload

               Array.from(this.Form.UploadFiles).forEach(file => {
               this.uploadFile(file) // each file gets sent to uploadFile() individually
               });
     },

     async uploadFile(File) {
                const FormFile = new FormData();
                FormFile.append("PostFile", File);

                await this.$axios.post('/api', FormFile).then(response => {
                    console.log("Successfully uploaded")
                }).catch(err => {
                    console.log(err.response.data.error)
                })
                return true;
      },

      async sendForm() {
            const FormBody = new FormData();
            FormBody.append("Name", this.Form.Name);
            FormBody.append("Description", this.Form.Description);
            // Here I need to wait for all files to upload first!
            await this.uploadFile();
            // If all files uploaded then post the form
            await this.$axios.post('/api', FormBody)
      }
```

Because `uploadFile()` returns `true` after each individual upload, the `sendForm()` will submit after the first file is uploaded. But I need to await until ALL files in `this.Form.UploadFiles` array are uploaded. How could I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can make `selectFiles` as `async` and use a for Loop instead of `forEach()`

```
async selectFile() {
    const this.Form.UploadFiles = this.$refs.PostFiles.files; // all files selected by user to upload

    for (const eachFile of Array.from(this.Form.UploadFiles)) {
        await this.uploadFile(eachFile); // each file gets sent to uploadFile() individually
    }
}



async sendForm() {
        const FormBody = new FormData();
        FormBody.append("Name", this.Form.Name);
        FormBody.append("Description", this.Form.Description);
        // Here I need to wait for all files to upload first!
        await this.selectFile();   //<--this is the change you need
        // If all files uploaded then post the form
        await this.$axios.post('/api', FormBody)
  }
```

Comment: Thank you - but I need `sendForm` to `await` before making its axios request. How do I do that?

Comment: @volumeone Oh, you are not awaiting for `selectFile()` in `sendForm` instead you are awaiting for `uploadFile`.  **Edit: Instead of awaiting for uploadFile, do it for `selectFile`**

Comment: this is great. out of interest why does `await` in `selectFile` only work in a loop and not in `forEach()`? I tried it with `forEach` and I get an error that `await` can only be used in an async function.... which `async selectFile()` is?

Comment: @volumeone, The error which you got would be because you wouldn't have made the callback of `forEach()` as async, something like: `forEach(async(file) => {})`. This would remove the error. But somehow `await` doesn't work in ForEach, I do not have much knowledge about it.

Comment: Sorry to come back but this is not working for me. ` await this.selectFile()` invokes the `selectFile()` function again. So I changed it to `await this.selectFile` but then it doesn't wait for selectFile to complete uploading...

Comment: @volumeone Okay so instead of `select file` do you need upload file in `sendForm()`? So when do you call `selectFile()`

Comment: Looks like I needed to wrap the loop in a Promise.all() and change the loop to a map. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61687762/how-to-wait-for-a-loop-to-finish-in-an-async-function-before-executing-code-in-a/61688130#61688130

Answer (score 1):

Try it with this approach:

```
 async selectFile() {
           const this.Form.UploadFiles = this.$refs.PostFiles.files; // all files selected by user to upload

           let allFiles = Array.from(this.Form.UploadFiles);
           for(let i = 0; i < allFiles.length; i++){
              console.log("Uploaded File number: " + i + 1);
              await this.uploadFile(allFiles[i])
           }

 },

 uploadFile(File) {
            const FormFile = new FormData();
            FormFile.append("PostFile", File);
            return this.$axios.post('/api', FormFile);
  },

  async sendForm() {
        const FormBody = new FormData();
        FormBody.append("Name", this.Form.Name);
        FormBody.append("Description", this.Form.Description);
        // Here I need to wait for all files to upload first!
        this.selectFile();
        // If all files uploaded then post the form
        await this.$axios.post('/api', FormBody)
  }
```

Comment: Thank you - does this allow for paralell uploading? Because `uploadFile` is not `async` anymore in this example.

Comment: in this case upload returning the promise from axios. what happens here is following: after you trigger `sendForm` method it will execute the function till `this.selectFile()`, inside of `selectFile()` there i iterate over all files with a `for` loop because `for` loops are synchronouse. with `await` i wait till the promise of `uploadFile` settles and continue the loop. your images will get uploaded one by one