# firebase storage execute code after multiple file upload

Tags: javascript, firebase, async-await, firebase-storage

I'm trying to redirect to another page after all the file are done uploading to firebase storage. It keep executing the redirect code before finishing the uploads. Can't figure out how to execute one after the other. This is a js scripts running on client side of the website.

```js
if (file[0].files[0]) {
  uploadFile(file[0]);
}
if (file[1].files[0]) {
  uploadFile(file[1]);
}
if (file[2].files[0]) {
  uploadFile(file[2]);
}

console.log("All files finished");
window.location.href = "success.html";

function uploadFile(file) {
  var task = storage.ref("arts/" + emailValue + Date.now()).put(file.files[0]);

  task.on('state_changed',

    function progess(snapshot) {
      var progressValue = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
      console.log(progressValue);
    },
    function error(err) {
      console.log(err);
    },
    function completed() {
      console.log('file upload success');
      task.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(downloadURL) {
        imgUrl = downloadURL;
        storeDetails();
      });

    }

  );
}

function storeDetails() {

  db.collection("participants").doc(emailValue + Date.now()).set({
      email: emailValue,
      url: imgUrl.toString(),
    })
    .then(function() {
      console.log("Document successfully written!");

    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
    })
}
```

Comment: You have no async await here so you will try to upload and immediately redirect. Why tag async await i you do not actually use it even though your code really needs it?

Comment: I tried using async and await but didn't work for me don't know how to implement it in my scenario.

Comment: Have a [look](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+async+await+upload+files+site:stackoverflow.com) for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61676984/how-to-async-await-multiple-uploads-before-final-form-submit

Comment: I tried changing the code didn't work (made the upload function async and wait in the task.on)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Returned a promise from the uploadFile and storeDetail functions then made the submit function async and await for uploadFile function call, for complete.

```
submitButton.addEventListener("click", async function () {

        if (file[0].files[0]) {
            await uploadFile(file[0], progressBar[0]);
        }
        if (file[1].files[0]) {
            await uploadFile(file[1], progressBar[1]);
        }
        if (file[2].files[0]) {
            await uploadFile(file[2], progressBar[2]);
        }

        console.log("All files finished");
    }
})

    function storeDetails() {
    return new Promise((resolve, _reject) => {
        db.collection("participants").doc(emailValue + Date.now()).set({
            email: emailValue,
            url: imgUrl.toString(),
        })
            .then(function () {
                console.log("Document successfully written!");
                resolve("success")              
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
            })
    });
}

function uploadFile(file, progressBar) {
    return new Promise((resolve, _reject) => {
        var task = storage.ref("arts/" + emailValue + Date.now()).put(file.files[0]);

        task.on('state_changed',

            function progess(snapshot) {
                var progressValue = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
                console.log(progressValue);
                progressBar.style.width = progressValue + '%';
            },
            function error(err) {
                console.log(err);
            },
            function completed() {
                console.log('file upload success');
                task.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(async function (downloadURL) {
                    imgUrl = downloadURL;
                    await storeDetails();
                    resolve("Completed");
                });
                
            }

        );
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `put` method returns a promise, so you can wait for that to resolve instead of passing in the callbacks. When doing that, the code to upload the file and then store its download URL in the database becomes:

```
function uploadFile(file) {
  const filename = emailValue + Date.now();
  storage.ref("arts/" + filename).put(file.files[0]).then(() => {
      task.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((downloadURL) => {
        db.collection("participants").doc(emailfilename).set({
          email: emailValue,
          url: downloadURL.toString()
        })
      });
    }
  );
}
```

Note there are quite some subtle changes in the above code, so:

1. There may be syntax errors as I didn't run this, so treat it as pseudo-code. If you get an error, first try to solve it yourself please - and if you do, post a comment or edit to the answer with the fix.
2. If you also need progress reporting, you can listen for `state_changed`. Just ignore the `completed` event as that is handled by `then()` in the code above.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is not quite what I'm trying I'm trying to upload multiple files one after the other with my uploadFile function

Comment: Your answer gave me idea for a workaround answer for my problem. It's a little messy code but works. Thanks man. I returned a promise from my uploadFile function and created a nested then until all 3 files are done.

Comment: Edited a little more instead of making nested then I made those uploadFile function await now its more clean code

Comment: I sure will do that. I cant upvote I'm low on rank.

Comment: You should still be able to accept the answer, which is independent on your reputation.